# How to set excelsheet row height to auto so that the content can autofit in the cell using exceljs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, export-to-excel, exceljs

I am using [exceljs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/exceljs) npm to export data in excelsheet. As my content in the cell is huge so I wanted text to be wrapped in the cell and should take enough height to show full content. I tried by giving fixed width -

```
worksheet.getRow(1).height = 20;
```

The problem with fixed height is that if my content is large than this size then it won't fit in the cell and it shows cropped text like shown in the screenshot.

[image]

I wanted cells to look like this [image]

I have gone through the exceljs documentation but didn't find anything.

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 2):

Have you already tried not to define the height of the row? I had the same problem and I solved it like this and that way the height of the row adjusts automatically.

I hope the solution I applied in my case is useful to you. Greetings.

Answer (score 1):

what worked for me was ,

```
worksheet.addRow(temp);
const row = worksheet.lastRow;
row.getCell(3).alignment = { wrapText: true };
```

when ever a new row is added, that rows 3rd cell alignment has to be set.

or

once all the rows are added in that sheet , iterated over all the rows and set the alignment property.

Comment: it doesnt work for cell on merge. the text is ellipsize with blank . its only work with 1 cell where doesnt or not in merge cell .

Comment: @YogiArifWidodo anysolution ?

Comment: not yet. @ChiKaLiO

Comment: `\r\n` to ... its not autoHeight . oh no #2023 still on same issue

Comment: i have ever solve the issue but i forgot how , in my old project lol

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:
Foreach on your data and get the desired row through the index

```
const row = worksheet.getRow(index);
    row.height = row.height * 20 / row.width;
```

*NOTE:

- I fixed the number '20', but you can also make it a variable
- In my excel, my data data starts at line four onwards, so I do:

  ```
   const row = worksheet.getRow(index + 4);
  ```

Comment: Thanks @allan, seems like above solution does not work if we have large content in a column.

Comment: @ShivamKubde If you raise 20, doesn't it work?

Comment: It would work if I raise it. But I have to raise/decrease it dynamically according to content length. We can set column height as per content length by keeping some variable, But I am looking for exceljs method or props which will do it for me.

Comment: @ShivamKubde were you able to solve this issue ? even am stuck in the same problem and in document i do not see any configuration parameter for this .

Comment: @anilkumard I didn't found any solid solution, but for temporary I am setting row height as per content length. height = cell.value.toString().trim().length; row.height = height > 20 ? height * 2 / 3 : 20;

Comment: only thing that worked for me was , set the cell width and then set that column or cell with wrapText: true

Answer (score 0):

The exceljs library does not provide a straightforward method to automatically adjust row heights based on the content in the cells.

For temporary, set row height as per content length. It work for me

```
row.height = cell.value.toString().trim().length
```

From Shivam Kubde's comment

Answer (score 0):

Do not mention the height that's automatically set. You need to use the following:

```
let rowValue = worksheet.addRow(RecordValues);
rowValue.eachCell(cell => {
       cell.alignment = 
{ horizontal: 'center',vertical :'middle' ,wrapText: true};
})
```

Here, RecordValues is the table of displayed values.

Answer (score 0):

I was working on a similar issue, this is how i solved it

```
this.xlRow = 18

    let slno = 1

    console.log(excelData.data.inoviceDetails)
    excelData.data.inoviceDetails.forEach((d: any) => {
        this.xlCol = 1

        // worksheet.getCell(this.xlRow, this.xlCol++).value = slno

        let cell1  = worksheet.getCell(this.xlRow, this.xlCol++);
        cell1.value = slno
        cell1.alignment = {vertical :'top'}


        let cell2 = worksheet.getCell(this.xlRow, this.xlCol++);
        cell2.value = d.particular;
        cell2.alignment = { wrapText: true, vertical :'top' };  // Enable text wrapping
        
        // worksheet.getCell(this.xlRow, 9).value = d.value
        let cell3 = worksheet.getCell(this.xlRow, 9)
        cell3.value = d.value
        cell3.alignment = {vertical :'top'}

        // Merge cells from B to H
        let m1 = worksheet.getCell(this.xlRow, 2);  // Cell B
        let m2 = worksheet.getCell(this.xlRow, 8);  // Cell H
        worksheet.mergeCells(m1.address, m2.address);

        var row = worksheet.getRow(this.xlRow);
        row.height = row.getCell(2).toString().trim().length/4

        slno++

        this.xlRow++;
    }
    );
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).