# How to Auto resize row in excelJs?

Tags: javascript, exceljs

[How to set excelsheet row height to auto so that the content can autofit in the cell using exceljs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66364840/13321172)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set excelsheet row height to auto so that the content can autofit in the cell using exceljs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66364840/how-to-set-excelsheet-row-height-to-auto-so-that-the-content-can-autofit-in-the)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by doing a loop as shown below:

```js
const workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
const sheet1 = workbook.addWorksheet('sheet1');

  for (let i = 0; i < sheet1.columns.length; i += 1) { 
    let dataMax = 0;
    const column = sheet1.columns[i];
    for (let j = 1; j < column.values.length; j += 1) {
      const columnLength = column.values[j].length;
      if (columnLength > dataMax) {
        dataMax = columnLength;
      }
    }
    column.height = dataMax < 10 ? 10 : dataMax;
  }
```

[Source](https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs/issues/83)

Comment: I have tried it, It is not working. The row is not getting resized

Comment: I've edited my post, can you try this new one please @ISHITAPRAMANICK

Comment: This will increase the width of the column. My requirements is to increase the height of the row

Comment: @ISHITAPRAMANICK I am sorry. I made a new edit again

Answer (score 0):

Although initially I do not know that it can be done. If it can be started with a certain cell height:

```
yourDataArray.forEach((e, index) => {

 worksheet.getRow(index).height = 28;         // Height for file = 28 inches

 worksheet.addRow({
    ...e                                        // data Object [Destructuring][1]
  })
}
´´´


  [1]: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

Foreach on your data and get the desired row through the index

```
const row = worksheet.getRow(index);
row.height = row.height * 20 / row.width;
```

*NOTE:

- I fixed the number '20', but you can also make it a variable
- In my excel, my data data starts at line four onwards, so I do:

  ```
   const row = worksheet.getRow(index + 4);
  ```